# Angularjs controller works differently in old browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I met a strange problem when using `angular js`.

When I test my code in `netscape 9.0`, I found some page data is not rendered. Some expressions remain what they are(it shows `{{data}}` rather than `rendered data`).
When I test my code in Konqueror, I found controller did not even work.
What is stranger is that when I refresh the page, all things goes well.
I used `$(document).ready(function() {})` to make sure all `js` were loaded. 
So I'm pretty confused. Is there any possible this problem is cause by browsers?
Here I list some of my code．

```
var viewClientModule = angular.module('view', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'localization'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl: './home.html',
         controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
}]);
viewClientModule.controller("HomeCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', '$rootScope',
   function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope) {
   $scope.init = function() {
      //xxxx
   };

   $scope.init();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 support is dropped in Angular 1.3, and IE8 was released in 2009. Netscape 9 was released in 2007 and was discontinued in 2008.

Even though the Angular docs doesn't explicitly say that Netscape 9 is not supported you should not expect it to work in such an old browser.

If you really need to support browsers that old, Angular is probably not a very good choice.

Comment: Almost - IE8 support will be dropped with AngularJS 1.3. By now (1.2.19) it is still working. See the [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Googling confirms it so I've no idea now where I got 1.2 from. I'll edit my post and fix.